# Do I need to apply for a Transit Visa for Madrid airport layover if I travel from Uruguay to India, holding a US B1/B2 visa?

Tags: visas, transit, madrid

Do I need to apply for a separate Transit Visa for Madrid airport layover if I travel from Uruguay to India, holding a US B1/B2 visa ?

Comment: What is your citizenship, and are both flights on the same ticket, or are they booked separately?

Answer (score 1):

Would be helpful if we knew what passport you hold (which country issued it).

Nationals of the following countries require a visa to transit through the international area of any airport located in the territory of the Schengen States in order to take a connecting flight to a country outside the Schengen area.

Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Ghana, Iran, Iraq, Nigeria, Pakistan, Somalia and Sri Lanka.

In addition, nationals of the following countries require a visa to transit through the international area of any airport located in Spain in order to take a connecting flight to a country outside the Schengen area:

Cameroon, Côte d'Ivoire, Cuba, Djibouti, Gambia, Guinea, Guinea-Bissau, India, Liberia, Mali, Republic of the Congo, Sierra Leone, Syria, Togo and Yemen. Holders of passports issued by the Palestinian Authority also require a visa.

Nationals of the States included on the foregoing lists do not require an airport transit visa if they have a Schengen visa, or another type of visa, or a residence card permitting their return, issued by a Member State of the European Union or of the European Economic Area (EEA) or  Switzerland, or by Andorra, Canada, the United States of America, Japan, or San Marino, or by any of the overseas countries and territories of the Kingdom of the Netherlands, or if they are a diplomatic passport holder, or a family member of a citizen of the EU or of the EEA, or a flight crew member of a State that is party to the International Civil Aviation Organization.

The [Spanish Embassy in Uruguay](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/montevideo/es/Paginas/index.aspx) will be able to answer any specific questions you might have.